# Как глобализировать переменную не в main пакете

Tags: golang

Как мне глобализировать мою переменную `easyConnection` не в `main` пакете, а в своем собственном пакете `rbr_go:`

**httpConnection.go:**

```
package rbr_go

func EzConnection(host string, port int) {
    req, err := http.Get(host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error!")
    } else {
        var easyConnection = req.Body
    }
}

func OutInfo() {
    fmt.Println(easyConnection)
}
```

Сделать так чтоб я смог использовать переменную не только в родной функции, а и в других функциях моего `httpConnection.go` файла.

Answer (score 0):

Body имеет интерфейсный тип io.ReadCloser. Следовательно в файле импортируете io и на уровне пакета объявляете глобальную переменную этого типа:

```
var easyConnection io.ReadCloser
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы переменная была видна их других мест, её нужно объявлять так же, как другие публичные методы и переменные. То есть, с заглавной буквы.

```
var MyGlobalVariable = "example"
```

Comment: не находит в другой функции. undefined: EasyConnection

Comment: Если это в другом модуле, то нужно импортировать модуль и называть переменную по полному пути. Точно также как если бы вы хотели использовать функцию из того же модуля.

Comment: нет, это все в одном файле. Пробовал импортировать как функцию, пакет, httpConnection.EasyConnection, rbr_go.EasyConnection. Не могу понять как именно дописывать полный путь к переменной. Можете показать на примере пожалуйста

Comment: Покажите ваш код.